# How to toggle value of input based on adjacent element class with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I need to have the text input show the class name of the clicked element. Please see the following code:

[JSFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/y8KxK/8/)

[UPDATED DEMO with working solution by @arun-p-johny](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/UVhr2/4) (Thanks!)

**HMTL:**

```
<ol>
  <li>
      <input type="text" name="status{{photo.id}}" class="markinput" id="status{{photo.id}}" value="neutral" />
    <a href="#" class="mark neutral" title="Toggle yes, no or neutral."><b>Yes</b><i>No</i>Neutral</a>
  </li>
</ol>
```

**jQuery:**

```
// Toggle between selected, rejected and neutral settings
var classNames = ['yes', 'no', 'neutral'];

$( '.mark' ).click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.toggleClass(function (i, className, b) {
        var ret_index;
        $.each(classNames, function (index, value) {
            if ($this.hasClass(value)) {
                ret_index = (index + 1) % classNames.length;
            }
        });
        $this.removeClass(classNames.join(' '));
        return classNames[ret_index];
        // Need to toggle value of input based on adjacent element class
        // $this.closest("input").val(?????????);
    });
});
```

Comment: your question is unclear to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
<ol>
    <li>
        <input type="text" name="status{{photo.id}}" class="markinput" id="status{{photo.id}}" value="neutral" /> 
        <a href="#" class="mark neutral" title="Toggle yes, no or neutral."><b data-class="yes">Yes</b><i data-class="no">No</i><span data-class="neutral">Neutral</span></a>
    </li>
</ol>
```

then

```
var classNames = ['yes', 'no', 'neutral'];

$('.mark').click(function (e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var clazz = $(e.target).data('class');
    $this.removeClass(classNames.join(' ')).addClass(clazz);
    $this.prev("input").val(clazz)
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/UVhr2/)

Comment: @sgriffee did you check the attached fiddle... the code has to be in dom ready handler

Comment: Arun: Yes, I checked. In your Fiddle it changes from Yes to No on first click, and then doesn't change again (never selects neutral). The input text needs to cycle between Yes, No and Neutral whenever the link is clicked.

Comment: @sgriffee I've made some changes to the html also... did you move that also... because the fiddle is working for me

Comment: Arun: Arun: I found the problem. Your code works, but I need to click specifically on each word in the link (Yes, No or Neutral) for it to toggle changes, whereas I wanted to click on one link (<a href="#">YesNoNeutral</a>) to toggle between the changes (is this possible?). Your solution may be the best after all. I'll experiment with it in my code and accept your answer if it works — thank you.